# does the context passed on getDefaultSharedPreferences affects the result?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I'm getting an weird error so I'm trying to eliminate the possibilities.

Does the context passed to `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()` changes the result?

I mean, when i'm writting setting to my app i never pay attention which context i pass to this method since it is a valid context...

Sometimes i put the `Activity`, sometimes the `Appliaction` whatever context i've on hands

Is it wrong? I've noticed that i'm getting wrong preferences values at some point, and i dont know if there is a bug in my code or if this be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether you provide an `Application` or an `Activity` as the `Context` parameter for `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`.

If you look at the source for `getDefaultSharedPreferences()`:

```
return context.getSharedPreferences(getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(context),
        getDefaultSharedPreferencesMode());
```

Looking further, into `getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(context)`:

```
return context.getPackageName() + "_preferences";
```

This means that for any `Context` of your application, you'll get the same `SharedPreferences` back, as your application ID does not change based on `Activity` or `Application`.

The only time you could run into a potential issue is if you are manually creating a `Context` for another package (e.g. using `Context.createPackageContext()`).

Answer (score 0):

`SharedPreferences` data stores all have a *name*, and as long as you use the same name you'll always get the same data store.

Hat tip to @kcoppock who has pointed out that in the particular case of `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`, the only thing the generated name is dependent on is the Context's package. Since any `Application` or `Activity` instance you pass is exceedingly likely to have the same package name, in your case you should always get the same data store.

There are other ways to retrieve `SharedPreferences` stores, though. `Activity.getPreferences()` will generate the name based on the Activity's class name, so calling `getPreferences()` from inside two different activities will give you two different data stores.

You can also call `Context.getSharedPreferences()` directly (both PreferenceManager and Activity just call through to this) and pass a data store name explicitly. There's no requirement for how the name should look; as long as you use the same name you'll always get the same data store.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: `getDefaultSharedPreferencesName()` constructs the preference file name from the `Context.getPackageName()` property, which is fixed for the application and won't change on an Activity basis.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I was thinking of `Activity.getPreferences()`, which uses the Activity's class name as the datastore name.